# String splitting loop through Dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, split, dataframe

I'm trying to use Python to loop through a dataframe column which is formatted as follows:

```
Town 1, AL, USA
Town 2, AL, USA
Town 3, AK, USA
Town 4, CA, USA
Town 5, DE, USA
Town 6, MI, USA
```

I have been trying to work with the `split()` method both with the original dataframe (which includes crime description and URL columns) and the column on its own, both as a dataframe and Series object.  Neither of those objects have method split() available to them.

The desired output will be another column of just the STATE abbreviation, so I understand that I am trying to find an equivalent of a `df.split(', ')` and to append the second [1] index from that split for a Series or dataframe.  (If I am mistaken, please correct me).

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods), e.g. `df["col"].str.split(", ").str[1]`:

```
>>> df
               col
0  Town 1, AL, USA
1  Town 2, AL, USA
2  Town 3, AK, USA
3  Town 4, CA, USA
4  Town 5, DE, USA
5  Town 6, MI, USA
>>> df["col"].str.split(", ")
0    [Town 1, AL, USA]
1    [Town 2, AL, USA]
2    [Town 3, AK, USA]
3    [Town 4, CA, USA]
4    [Town 5, DE, USA]
5    [Town 6, MI, USA]
Name: col, dtype: object
>>> df["col"].str.split(", ").str[1]
0    AL
1    AL
2    AK
3    CA
4    DE
5    MI
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.apply()` to execute some function on every element in column

```
import pandas as pd

data=[
    'Town 1, AL, USA',
    'Town 2, AL, USA',
    'Town 3, AK, USA',
    'Town 4, CA, USA',
    'Town 5, DE, USA',
    'Town 6, MI, USA',
]

df = pd.DataFrame( data )

print df

df['state'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])

print df
```

result

```
                 0
0  Town 1, AL, USA
1  Town 2, AL, USA
2  Town 3, AK, USA
3  Town 4, CA, USA
4  Town 5, DE, USA
5  Town 6, MI, USA

                 0 state
0  Town 1, AL, USA    AL
1  Town 2, AL, USA    AL
2  Town 3, AK, USA    AK
3  Town 4, CA, USA    CA
4  Town 5, DE, USA    DE
5  Town 6, MI, USA    MI
```

---

**EDIT:**

BTW: I search on internet `pandas split column to new columns` and you can even split it to 3 new columns this way:

```
def split_more(x):
    return pd.Series( x.split(',') )

df[ ['town', 'state','country'] ] = df[0].apply(split_more)

print df
```

result:

```
                 0    town state country
0  Town 1, AL, USA  Town 1    AL     USA
1  Town 2, AL, USA  Town 2    AL     USA
2  Town 3, AK, USA  Town 3    AK     USA
3  Town 4, CA, USA  Town 4    CA     USA
4  Town 5, DE, USA  Town 5    DE     USA
5  Town 6, MI, USA  Town 6    MI     USA
```

Comment: can you point me to doc on what exactly the 'lambda' piece is doing?

Answer (score 2):

[Series have string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods) which are accessible through their `str` attribute. For example, you could use 
`df['addr'].str.extract`:

```
In [34]: df = pd.read_table('data', sep='-', header=None, names=['addr'])

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
              addr
0  Town 1, AL, USA
1  Town 2, AL, USA
2  Town 3, AK, USA
3  Town 4, CA, USA
4  Town 5, DE, USA
5  Town 6, MI, USA

In [36]: df[['Town', 'State', 'Country']] = df['addr'].str.extract(r'([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+)')

In [38]: del df['addr']
```

yields

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
     Town State Country
0  Town 1    AL     USA
1  Town 2    AL     USA
2  Town 3    AK     USA
3  Town 4    CA     USA
4  Town 5    DE     USA
5  Town 6    MI     USA
```

Comment: Great response.  Initially I thought I would only want to retain the State abbr (I am trying to build a chloropleth) but using this method will allow me to drill down to a better level of detail, if and when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

### Function `split_str_columns_df` loop to Split all string columns at once.

#### Also Generate new columns with the splits, and delete the old ones.

#### You choose your splitter: **`" "`** or   **`","`** or ....

Just introduce it in the function definition that you see above:

```
new = df[col].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
```

or if you want a **`,`** and split into 3 columns (n=2), you'll have to adapt a little bit the function to incorporate a 3rth column

```
new = df[col].str.split(", ", n = 2, expand = True)
```

#### Example Data: (the whole example data is located at the end of this post)

```
data_df.head(3)
```

.

```
    Rating          Score    Ocupation
0   RATINGSTUFE F   NaN      Animator Senior
1   RATINGSTUFE B   4.0      Animator
2   NaN             7.0      Art administrator
```

#### Call the function: **`split_str_columns_df(data_df,columns)`**

The columns I want to split are `'Rating'` and `'Ocupation'`.

```
columns=['Rating','Ocupation']
dff=split_str_columns_df(data_df,columns)
```

Output:

```
   Score     Rating_a Rating_b Ocupation_a    Ocupation_b
0    NaN  RATINGSTUFE        F    Animator         Senior
1    4.0  RATINGSTUFE        B    Animator           None
2    7.0          NaN      NaN         Art  administrator
```

**`split_str_columns_df(data_df,columns)`**

The function definitiopn that that I use is:

```
def split_str_columns_df(dataframe,str_columns):
    ''' Function that splits the str columns " " is the separation, create 2 new 
        columns and remove the original. If the column's name is 'Name' the 2 new columns will be 'Name_a' and 'Name_b'.'''
    # new data frame with split value columns 
    df=dataframe
    for i in range(len(str_columns)):
        col=str_columns[i]
        new_col1=col+'_a'
        new_col2=col+'_b'

        #Split
        new = df[col].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)   
        # making seperate first name column from new data frame 
        df[new_col1]= new[0]   
        # making seperate last name column from new data frame 
        df[new_col2]= new[1] 

        # Dropping old Name columns 
        df.drop(columns =[col], inplace = True)     
    return df
```

**Be Aware!**:

1. When splitting NaN values, the new 2 columns get nan  (both) (Col `Rating_a`, `Rating_b`
2. If a row contains 1 single word, when you split the 2nd column you'll get a **`None`** (Column `Ocupation_b`)
3. Realize that the original columns `Rating` and `Ocupations` are deleted and we have 
   `Rating_a` and `Rating_b`. And `Ocupations_a` and `Ocupations_b`.

Generate the data of the example:

```
data_df=pd.DataFrame(['RATINGSTUFE F', 'RATINGSTUFE B',np.nan, 'RATINGSTUFE L',
   'RATINGSTUFE G', np.nan, 'RATINGSTUFE M', 'RATINGSTUFE L',
   'RATINGSTUFE F', 'RATINGSTUFE M'], columns=['Rating'])

data_df['Score']=[np.nan,4,7,4,9,4,3,1,2,5]
data_df['Ocupation']=['Animator Senior', 'Animator', 'Art administrator', 'Animator Junior', 'Dancer', 'Colorist Junior', 'Ceramics artist', 'Chief creative officer','Colorist', 'Dancer']
```

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of comparing different methods with `%timeit`, I've found when working with strings in columns, list comprehensions are typically the winner.

```
In [1]: %paste 
import pandas as pd

data=[
    'Town 1, AL, USA',
    'Town 2, AL, USA',
    'Town 3, AK, USA',
    'Town 4, CA, USA',
    'Town 5, DE, USA',
    'Town 6, MI, USA',
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

## -- End pasted text --
Out[1]: 
                 0
0  Town 1, AL, USA
1  Town 2, AL, USA
2  Town 3, AK, USA
3  Town 4, CA, USA
4  Town 5, DE, USA
5  Town 6, MI, USA
```

**%timeit tests:**

```
In [2]: %timeit df['state'] = [x.split(',')[1] for x in df[0]]
1000 loops, best of 3: 350 µs per loop

In [3]: %timeit df['state'] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1])
1000 loops, best of 3: 671 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit df['state'] = df[0].str.split(", ").str[1]
100 loops, best of 3: 1.1 ms per loop
```